# Помогите с кодом!Делаю мини задачки, в конце выходит все правильно кроме 2 ошибок

Tags: java

```
public int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
        
        if (speed <= 60){
          speed = speed -5;
        return 0;
        }
        else if (speed >= 61 && speed<= 80){
          speed = speed -5;
            return 1;
        }
        else if (speed >=81){
          speed = speed -5;
            return 2;
        }
        if(isBirthday == true){
          speed = speed +5;
          return speed;
        }
    
    return speed;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
      if(isBirthday)
          speed -= 5;
        if (speed <= 60)
          return 0;
        else if (speed >= 61 && speed<= 80)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
}
```